# Laravel Eloquent Query builder accessing postgres composite column attributes

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8, composite-types

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and Postgres 11 / Postgis 2.5.2 and have a `stdraddr` column, which is a composite type. I can successfully run a query like this directly on the table:

```
select * from addresses where (address).house_num like '%2840%'
```

to access the columns within the address column.

I have yet to translate this query to Eloquent with the following attempts:

`Address::where('address.house_num', 'LIKE', $houseNum)->get();`

`Address::where('(address).house_num', 'LIKE', $houseNum)->get();`

`Address::where('address[house_num]', 'LIKE', $houseNum)->get();`

`Address::where('address', 'LIKE', $houseNum)->get();`

`Address::where('house_num', 'LIKE', $houseNum)->get();`

`Address::whereRaw("(address).house_num LIKE {$houseNum}")->get();`

and a few others that have thrown SQLSTATE exceptions. The $houseNum variable includes the wildcard characters. Has anyone used composite types with eloquent?

I've been able to just run a raw query: `\DB::select('select * from addresses where (address).house_num LIKE ?', [$houseNum]);`, but curious if Eloquent can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `whereRaw()` with the code and binding from your raw query:

```php
Address::whereRaw('(address).house_num LIKE ?', [$houseNum])->get();
```